# find hidden URL for streaming radio

Tags: streaming

I would like to find a utility that can find the hidden URL to eg this [streaming radio](http://yp.shoutcast.com/sbin/tunein-station.pls?id=1280625)

so I can use that in mocp (music on console player). 
URLsnooper is there for windows, but I can't find an alternative for Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This playlist is readable with any old text-editor, which will reveal the URL?

```
[playlist]
numberofentries=1
File1=http://91.121.91.110:4000
Title1=(#1 - 26/150) M2 CALIENTE : ONLY LATIN MUSIC - Live From Paris France - www.m2radio.fr
Length1=-1
Version=2
```

So unless you mean something else entirely, the url you are looking for is `http://91.121.91.110:4000` ?

In that case the utility is anything that can read txt files (Vim, gedit, less, more, cat etc :)  )

For clarity, this is what I did:

1. go to that url in my browser, and save it as a file

   - alternatively you could use "wget" in the commandline to download it.
   - the object of this step is to get that file (called tinein-station.pls) on your computer
2. Open the file with any program that you would use to read .txt files. This can be LibreOffice, MS-Word, Gedit, anything you wish.

   - you could even rename the file as playlist.txt and let `nautilus` figure out what to use :)
3. You see above contents, and there is the hidde url (3rd line)

This is the failsave commandline version:

1. open a terminal (ctrl-alt T, or find it in the menu)
2. type `wget http://yp.shoutcast.com/sbin/tunein-station.pls?id=1280625`

   - you will see something ending like

     ```
     2012-11-12 16:18:47 (13.5 MB/s) - `tunein-station.pls?id=1280625' saved [176/176]
     ```
3. type `cat tunein-station.pls\?id\=1280625`

   - you will see the contents as described above :)

Comment: Thanks Nanne, http://91.121.91.110:4000 is exactly what I needed. Can you explain how you got this? I do use gvim as text editor, but haven't got a clue as how you got that address. All I see is http://yp.shoutcast.com/sbin/tunein-station.pls?id=1280625

Comment: I've added what I did to the answer :D

Comment: I wonder why this one doesn't work? It does make an index.html but I don't see a usable address in it.                        wget http://radioplus.be/#/nieuws+/welkom

Comment: we're getting a bit offtopic now because there are loads different ways to stream music, and above method works for the .pls method from the initial question. But maybe you can use this link: http://od.mp3.streampower.be/vrt/radio1/11_11niws-snip_hi.mp3

Comment: Thank you once again! I don't see why it's off topic; the link that you gave me just now does work in mocp, whereas I simply didn't find any usefull hidden address in the original site.